# Show images in XSL like a WPF WrapPanel

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have an XML data file that contains a number of image paths that are displayed in a table using the following XSL style

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfShoeprintDetails/ShoeprintDetails">
<table border="2" Width="50" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" style="font-family:arial">
<tr>
<th align="right">Reference</th>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="Reference"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align="right">Images</th>
<td>
<xsl:for-each select="Images/ShoeImage">
<img width="100" height="auto">
<xsl:attribute name="src">
<xsl:value-of select="DecryptedFilename"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</img>
</xsl:for-each>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, one table is generated for each root element in the XML file with two rows for the reference and the images.

The images are designed to be displayed in a nested table in the second row, second column.

The problem is that the table keeps expanding to hold the images in one line (there could potentially be up to 15 images. However I would like the images to "Wrap" so that a maximum of say 5 images are shown and then it starts a new row in the table, but I have no idea how this might be accomplished.

I have tried not using a nested table but this displays the images in a stack one on top of the other and not side by side.

The rationale behind this is that I would like to print the document off and some images are being cut off when printing.

- XSL (not FO)
- XML
- Displaying in WPF Browser Control
- Dynamically created XSL file in C#
- Visual Studio 2012

EDIT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ReportTemplate.xsl"?>
<ArrayOfShoeprintDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ShoeprintDetails>
<Reference>Item 1</Reference>
<Images>
<ShoeImage>
<DecryptedFilename>C:\79136</DecryptedFilename>
</ShoeImage>
<ShoeImage>
<DecryptedFilename>C:\79137</DecryptedFilename>
</ShoeImage>
<ShoeImage>
<DecryptedFilename>C:\79138</DecryptedFilename>
</ShoeImage>
<ShoeImage>
<DecryptedFilename>C:\79139</DecryptedFilename>
</ShoeImage>
<ShoeImage>
<DecryptedFilename>C:\79140</DecryptedFilename>
</ShoeImage>
<ShoeImage>
<DecryptedFilename>C:\79141</DecryptedFilename>
</ShoeImage>
<ShoeImage>
<DecryptedFilename>C:\79142</DecryptedFilename>
</ShoeImage>
<Images>
</ShoeprintDetails>
</ArrayOfShoeprintDetails>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your XML (with 6 or more images in) please? It shouldn't actually be too much effort to start a new table row for every 5 images. Thanks!

Comment: This is more of an html question. Are the images of fixed size?

Comment: No They arent, I set the image width and let the height scale automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted only five images per row (and were not concerned about the size of each image), the approach to take is to start off by selecting the images that would occur first in each row; i.e the 1st, 6th, 11th (etc) images

```
 <xsl:for-each select="Images/ShoeImage[position() mod 5 = 1]">
```

Then, to for each such image, you would get the images that make up the row, like so

```
 <xsl:for-each select=".|following-sibling::ShoeImage[position() &lt; 5]" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="imagesPerRow" select="5" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfShoeprintDetails/ShoeprintDetails">
    <table border="2" Width="50" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" style="font-family:arial">
      <tr>
        <th align="right">Reference</th>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Reference"/></td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Images/ShoeImage[position() mod $imagesPerRow = 1]">
        <tr>
          <th align="right">Images</th>
          <td>
             <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::ShoeImage[position() &lt; $imagesPerRow]" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ShoeImage">
   <img width="100" height="auto" src="{DecryptedFilename}" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note I have paramterised the "5" here, and I also switched to using `xsl:apply-templates` simply to cut down on indentation!

Also note the use of Attribute Value Templates in creating the `src` attribute. The curly braces `{ }` indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.

EDIT: This is more of an HTML issue, that XSLT, but if you wanted to only show the "Images" header cell once, try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
<xsl:param name="imagesPerRow" select="5" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="ArrayOfShoeprintDetails/ShoeprintDetails">
    <table border="2" Width="50" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" style="font-family:arial">
      <tr>
        <th align="right">Reference</th>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Reference"/></td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:variable name="images" select="Images/ShoeImage" />
      <xsl:for-each select="$images[position() mod $imagesPerRow = 1]">
        <tr>
          <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
             <th align="right" rowspan="{ceiling(count($images) div 5)}">Images </th>
          </xsl:if>
          <td>
             <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::ShoeImage[position() &lt; $imagesPerRow]" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ShoeImage">
   <img width="100" height="auto" src="{DecryptedFilename}" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is brilliant and it works well, Is there any way to get the Images header to only display on the first row of the images?

Comment: I've added another sample to my answer, to show this.